# Expression of cosine and sine of $\frac{\phi}{3}$

Tags: trigonometry

For $n\in \mathbb{N}$ it holds that $\left (\cos \phi +i\sin \phi \right )^n=\cos \left (n\phi \right ) +i\sin \left (n\phi \right )$.

How can we derive from that an expression of cosine and sine of $\frac{\phi}{3}$ ?

Or do we use the identity $e^{i\phi }=\cos \phi +i\sin \phi $ ?

Then we would have $e^{i\frac{\phi}{3} }=\cos\frac{\phi}{3} +i\sin \frac{\phi}{3}$ and $e^{i\frac{-\phi}{3} }=\cos\frac{-\phi}{3} +i\sin \frac{-\phi}{3}$.

It holds that $\cos (-x)=\cos (x)$ and $\sin (-x)=-\sin (x)$.

Therefore we get $e^{i\frac{-\phi}{3} }=\cos\frac{\phi}{3} -i\sin \frac{\phi}{3}$.

So it follows that $e^{i\frac{\phi}{3} }+ e^{i\frac{-\phi}{3} }=2\cos\frac{\phi}{3}\Rightarrow \cos\frac{\phi}{3}=\frac{e^{i\frac{\phi}{3} }+ e^{i\frac{-\phi}{3} }}{2}$.

Respectively we have that $e^{i\frac{\phi}{3} }- e^{i\frac{-\phi}{3} }=2i\sin\frac{\phi}{3}\Rightarrow \sin\frac{\phi}{3}=\frac{e^{i\frac{\phi}{3} }- e^{i\frac{-\phi}{3} }}{2i}$.

Is that correct?

Comment: Not quite: in the expression for $\sin \phi/3$ it should be $2i$ in the denominator.

Comment: I edited it. Is now everything correct? @TobyMak

Comment: Yes, everything is correct.

Comment: So we cannot use the property $\left (\cos \phi +i\sin \phi \right )^n=\cos \left (n\phi \right ) +i\sin \left (n\phi \right )$, do we? @TobyMak

Comment: No, you cannot here.

Comment: Ok! Thank you!! :-) @TobyMak

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Any* $z$ satisfies$$\exp\pm iz=\cos z\pm i\sin z\implies\cos z=\frac{\exp iz+\exp-iz}{2},\,\sin z=\frac{\exp iz-\exp-iz}{2i},$$including $z=\phi,\,z=\frac{\phi}{3}$. It's worth nothing the values of $\cos\phi,\,\sin\phi$ don't determine those of $\cos\frac{\phi}{3},\,\sin\frac{\phi}{3}$: equivalently, $\exp i\phi$ doesn't determine $\exp\frac{i\phi}{3}$. For example, $\exp i\phi=1$ is consistent with $\exp\frac{i\phi}{3}$ being any of the three cube roots of unity.

Comment: Thank you!! :-)